# Excel Get & Transform (Power Query) M Code Style and Performance

Tags: excel, performance, powerquery, m

I've created a few reasonably complex M queries and have started running into some severe performance issues. I'm wondering if has to do with how I sometime organize my code.

The issues I've been having are:

1) Power Query constantly uses all of several CPU cores, calculating *something*, even if I'm not waiting for a result.

2) In task manager I can sometimes see that the Power Query threads ("Microsoft.mashup.Container.NetFX40.exe") are nearly idle, while Excel.exe is using 100% of one core for tens of minutes - even though at most I'm looking values in a few parameter tables that don't contain more than a couple dozen cells.

3) Some steps take extremely long to calculate, even though the operations involved are trivial. For example, I have a list of 10 text values taken from an Excel table. This list appears as one of my query steps when I 'preview' it. Then I want to remove a single value, so the next step = List.RemoveItems(myList, {"val"}). It didn't compute after 30 minutes, even though I could see the list was correctly loaded in a previous step.

4) UI sometimes becomes unresponsive for several minutes after changing code. Can still right-click on Queries at left hand side to enter advanced editor, and click the red X at top right and choose to keep changes, but all the rest is unresponsive. Not greyed out, just unresponsive.

Anyway, I just wanted to ask if anyone's had similar trouble, and if anyone knows what triggers particularly bad performance in PQ.

I'll often use something like the following pattern to keep the total number of queries down while still being able to easily inspect individual steps:

```
let
    ThisWB = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
    CfgTbl = ThisWB{[Name="myCfgTbl"]}[Content],
    x = aFn(CfgTbl),
    y = bFn(CfgTbl),
    output = [ThisWB=ThisWB, CfgTbl=CfgTbl, x=x, y=y]
in
    output
```

Is this likely to lead to any issues? Just thought it might because at one point after waiting a very long time for a simple function result, I created a new query = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="myCfgTbl"]}[Content], referenced it from the other query, and my result calculated immediately. No idea why.

Comment: What version of Power Query are you using? Some of the CPU issues may be due to background analysis, which you can turn off for a document in the Options dialog under Current Workbook | Data Load | Allow data preview to download in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It calculates previews. Turn off auto preview generation.
2. I messed with something like this in cases with formula-heavy tables.

The rest probably requires code examples, especially your last case.

BTW, is your version of power query (or Excel 2016) up-to-date?

Comment: Thanks, previews were most of my problem. In addition, this [link](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/11/20/referenced-queries-and-caching-in-power-bi-and-power-query/) takes some focus to read, but helps me understand how to optimize queries.

Comment: @alazyworkaholic Thanks, that's a lot of useful information!